# Strange error from move and copy constructors that have shared_ptrs

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm getting the following errors when trying compile my HuffmanNode class for an assignment, it seems to be something to do with the shared_ptrs in the class, but I have no idea as to what is actually going wrong because of the sheer amount of text that I can't seem to find the actual problem.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c src/HuffmanNode.cpp -o obj/HuffmanNode.o -I headers
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:63,
                 from headers/HuffmanNode.hpp:9,
                 from src/HuffmanNode.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; _Args = {const std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}; _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; _Args = {const std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}; _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:526:39:   required from ‘std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<_Tp, _Alloc, _Lp>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace(_Alloc, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}; _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; _Alloc = std::allocator<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:637:4:   required from ‘std::__shared_count<_Lp>::__shared_count(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, _Tp*, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; _Alloc = std::allocator<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>; _Args = {const std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1295:35:   required from ‘std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Alloc = std::allocator<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>; _Args = {const std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}; _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:344:64:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Alloc = std::allocator<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>; _Args = {const std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}; _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:690:14:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp> std::allocate_shared(const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; _Alloc = std::allocator<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>; _Args = {const std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:706:39:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; _Args = {const std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}]’
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:34:72:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(const std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:41:1: note: candidate: FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode&&)
 HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(HuffmanNode &&n)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:41:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>’ to ‘FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode&&’
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:33:1: note: candidate: FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(const FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode&)
 HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(const HuffmanNode &n)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:33:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>’ to ‘const FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode&’
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:11:1: note: candidate: FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(char, int, std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>, std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>)
 HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(char c, int f, std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> l, std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> r)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:11:1: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:63,
                 from headers/HuffmanNode.hpp:9,
                 from src/HuffmanNode.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; _Args = {std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}; _Tp
= FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; _Args = {std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}; _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:526:39:   required from ‘std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<_Tp, _Alloc, _Lp>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace(_Alloc, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&};
_Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; _Alloc = std::allocator<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:637:4:   required from ‘std::__shared_count<_Lp>::__shared_count(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, _Tp*, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; _Alloc = std::allocator<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>; _Args = {std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1295:35:   required from ‘std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Alloc = std::allocator<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>; _Args = {std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}; _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:344:64:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Alloc = std::allocator<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>; _Args = {std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}; _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:690:14:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp> std::allocate_shared(const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; _Alloc = std::allocator<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>; _Args = {std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:706:39:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode; _Args = {std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&}]’
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:93:52:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:41:1: note: candidate: FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode&&)
 HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(HuffmanNode &&n)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:41:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>’ to ‘FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode&&’
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:33:1: note: candidate: FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(const FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode&)
 HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(const HuffmanNode &n)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:33:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>’ to ‘const FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode&’
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:11:1: note: candidate: FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(char, int, std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>, std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>)
 HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(char c, int f, std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> l, std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> r)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/HuffmanNode.cpp:11:1: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 1 provided
```

I've tried looking up the errors but can't seem to find anything that solves the problem.

I can't post my entire code due to it being an assignment, but the lines that are mentioned in the error text are my constructor declarations, and as stated above, the problem seems to lie in the shared_ptrs:

```
line 11:    HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(char c, int f,  std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> l, std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> r)

line 33:    HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(const HuffmanNode &n) : ch(n.ch), freq(n.freq), left(std::make_shared<HuffmanNode>(n.left)), right(std::make_shared<HuffmanNode>(n.right))

line 41:    HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(HuffmanNode &&n) : ch(std::move(n.ch)), freq(std::move(n.freq)), left(std::move(n.left)), right(std::move(n.right))
```

**EDIT:**

Here's what I can post according to the school regulations, the only method that has any content inside it of the problem areas is the move constructor, and that is just ensuring that there will be no double deletion errors when the destructor is called. This gives me the same errors as above does.

```cpp
#include <memory>

class HuffmanNode
{

    char ch;
    int freq;
    std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> left, right;

    // Node constructor for leaf node
    HuffmanNode(char c, int f, std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> l, std::shared_ptr<HuffmanNode> r)
        : ch(c), freq(f), left(l), right(r)
    {
        // Handled in initialiser list
    }

    HuffmanNode(const HuffmanNode &n)
        : ch(n.ch), freq(n.freq), left(std::make_shared<HuffmanNode>(n.left)),
          right(std::make_shared<HuffmanNode>(n.right))
    {
        // Handled by initialiser list
    }

    // Move Constructor
    HuffmanNode(HuffmanNode &&n)
        : ch(std::move(n.ch)), freq(std::move(n.freq)),
          left(std::move(n.left)),
          right(std::move(n.right))
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: The important bit is `error: no matching function for call to ‘FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode::HuffmanNode(const std::shared_ptr<FLNRHE001::HuffmanNode>&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }`

Comment: Post a [mcve] (without the line numbers) reproducing your problem as required here please.

Comment: You're attempting to pass a `shared_ptr` to construct an object that does not have a `shared_ptr` as its constructor's parameter, but a plain reference to an object, not even a pointer of any kind. That's what those error messages seem to indicate, but without an [mcve] this will not be possible to determine conclusively.

Comment: Now that you've added a few more clues: `right(std::make_shared<HuffmanNode>(n.right))` - "n.right" is already a shared_ptr. This valiant attempt to make_shared something that's already a shared pointer is unlikely to succeed.  make_shared is for creating a shared_ptr for something that's not. Furthermore, it is quite clear that this class doesn't even need you to specify a copy or a move constructor. The default copy and move constructors will work perfectly well.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've updated my question with an example that gives the same errors. Could you elaborate on what you were saying about the passing a shared_ptr as a reference to the object? I can't see where I would be doing that, but maybe it's something that I just haven't got the hang of yet.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry about my prior comment, you updated with a new comment while I was typing it. We specifically have to create a copy and move constructor according to the assignment text, I also found it weird when I started since it wasn't needed with the default as is, is there any way I can get around that or should I just leave a comment about the default working correctly?

Comment: I have no direct knowledge of your assignment, so I can't tell you what to do. It's possible that the purpose of your assignment is for you to be able to explicitly implement a proper copy and move constructor even when it's not needed. That's certainly a possibility, in which case you must do that correctly. I already explained what's the problem with the shown constructors are.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I got in touch with the lecturer, he said that the aim was to check our ability to create the constructors, I was told to adjust to not use the make_shared, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The errors were arising from attempting to use `make_shared` to create a copy of the left and right pointers, in this case I only require a shallow copy as is made by the `shared_ptr` copy constructor.

The corrected solution was only a change to the move constructor as follows-:

```
HuffmanNode(const HuffmanNode &n)
        : ch(n.ch), freq(n.freq), left(n.left),
          right(n.right)
    {
        // Handled by initialiser list
    }
```

Thanks to Sam Varshavchik for the help in this!